# Github actions yml reading a file and run specific commands

Tags: github, yaml, conditional-statements, github-actions

Is it possible to give yaml parameters to read a file from the repository and then execute specific commands based on that ? Like, lets say if the file contains x=1 then it will run specific commands or if x=2 some other commands will run ?

Comment: In a `run` step, you can run whatever shell commands you want, so your question becomes "can I do this in shell script?", and the answer is yes.

Comment: For example, to run a command if a file contains a string: `if grep -q 'x=1' myfile; then echo "The file contained the string"; fi`

Comment: Yes i considered that but i want yaml to read the file that is in my github repository. Doing this through a script would mean that i would first have to download the files to each new machine so my script can read it.

Comment: The script would run as part the GitHub Actions workflow, in a [`run` step](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun).

Comment: Oh yeh, i dont know what i was thinking. I'm gonna try that. Cheers !